# My ISR is executed only once even if I attempt to clear the Timer Flag

Tags: isr, pic32

I'm learning PIC32 and making some tests to make sure my ISRs are working properly. My test code is just turning a LED on and off in a time interval controlled by the ISR. 
Problem is, the ISR executes only once, and I don't get why.

I've tried the actual code to turn the LED on and off in the main function, with a timer between the turning on and off, it's working fine. 
I've tried different ways of clearing the interrupt flag to make sure it's cleared. but i can't say if it's actually ok or not.

here is the code

```
#include <p32xxxx.h>    
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <stdbool.h>        
#include <plib.h> 
#include <xc.h>

#define PIN_bypassled PORTEbits.RE4 
#define PIN_bypassledwrite LATEbits.LATE4 

//-------- ISRs   -----------------

//low speed timer 
void __ISR( _TIMER_2_VECTOR, ipl7) Swiching_loop( void)
{
//    INTDisableInterrupts();

    mT2ClearIntFlag();  //  first attempt to clear interrput flag
    IFS0bits.T2IF = 0;  //  second attempt to clear interrupt flag


    PIN_bypassledwrite = !PIN_bypassled;

//   INTEnableInterrupts();
 }

void main() {
    TRISE = 0x000000;
    SYSTEMConfigPerformance(80000000L);  //            INTEnableSystemSingleVectoredInt();


//    T1CON = 0X0010;                    //TMR1 Off, PRESCALE 1:256, 16b mode 
    PR1 = 100000; 
   mT1SetIntPriority(7);                //set priority interrupt level for timer 1 
    T1CON = 0x8030;                   //TMR1 ON, PRESCALE 1:256, 16b mode 
    mT1IntEnable(1);                      //

 //   T2CON = 0X0030;                    //TMR2 Off, PRESCALE 1:256, 16b mode 
    PR2 = 100000; 
    mT2SetIntPriority(7);                //set priority interrupt level for timer 2
    T2CON = 0x8070;                   //TMR2 ON, PRESCALE 1:256, 16b mode 
    mT2IntEnable(1);                      //

    INTEnableInterrupts();
    while (1){ 

  }
}
```

expected result would be my LED turning on and off, but instead it's just turning on. I interpret this as the ISR only executing once, but maybe i'm missing something since i'm under the impression that i'm clearing the interrupt flag correctly. 
What am i missing?

Comment: Do you have a handler for Timer 1?

Comment: It's the same one, I actually try to use both Timer 1 and 2 alternatively, just to make sure i got how to use different timers... this multiple or single vectored interrupt thingy is still not clear to me. 
But in this specific test, I only have this ISR, that i'd would like to  call from a Timer1 interrupt or a TImer2 interrupt, just for the sake of learning

Comment: IIRC, the default handler is a reset. If you run your code like you have posted it will reset on a first hit of a timer 1 interrupt.

Comment: Thanks, because of you, I could make it work

Still apparently there is also a problem if i set priorities for Timer1 and Timer2

    IPC1bits.T1IP = 6;              /* Set Timer 1 interrupt priority to 6 */
-> Commented, my ISR using Timer2 works perfectly
-> uncommented, the LED turns on once then doesn't turn on again... beeeecause, (thinking about this right now) the interrupt flag is common to all interrupts and it's been turned on by Timer1, but hasn't been cleared up, since there is not ISR for managing it ? i'll try to add an ISR just for resetting the flag and see how it goes

Comment: And that was the reason!!!!! thanks for your help!